# Sub Pages in Pico Install lead to 404

Tags: php, apache

I downloaded a lightweight PHP CMS solution called [Pico](http://pico.dev7studios.com/) and placed the files within my MAMP installation. When I visit the default homepage, everything seems to work, but upon clicking a link to a "sub page" (`http://localhost:8888/pico/subdir/`) I am taken to a generic 404 page. Since the sub pages are located within the `/content/` folder, do I need to make an adjustment to my MAMP install's .htaccess? Apache settings?

If anyone is familiar with Pico, I would like to know if I've missed a crucial install step.

Please feel free to ask any questions you may have.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to my own question. The contents of the `.htaccess` file should be [this](https://github.com/gilbitron/Pico/blob/master/.htaccess) (from the official Pico github). I'm not sure why this `.htaccess` file isn't included as part of the Pico download package...

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by changing the AllowOverride setup in Apache's site config to include the mod_rewrite directives http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

You also need to enable the "rewrite" module:

```
slady@slady ~ $ sudo a2enmod rewrite 
Enabling module rewrite.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
service apache2 restart
slady@slady ~ $ sudo service apache2 restart
[ ok ] Restarting web server: apache2 ... waiting ..
```

Comment: To expand on your answer, my solution was to edit my site config file, and change the AllowOverride directive from None to All.

Answer (score 0):

I recently downloaded Pico and had the same issue as you, but the htaccess file was included but everything was commented out. When I uncommented everything, but the intended comments, mind you, I was still getting my apache 404.

The solution for me was adding: `Options +FollowSymLinks` at the bottom of the htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add RewriteBase to your .htaccess

I have pico running as a subdirectory anyway so that might be the reason it's causing the issue. I hope someone can explain it better but this seems to work for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /your_site_dir/pico/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
    RewriteRule . index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

# Prevent file browsing 
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered so forgive me if I pull out the obvious, but make sure the WAMPserver Apache 'rewrite_module' is turned on (it's off by default) or the PICO rewrites won't function at all.